# How to dissolve "Reroute" nodes with python?

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor

I want to dissolve `REROUTE` nodes with Python.

Is there any way other than using `bpy.ops.node.delete_reconnect()`?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could search the node tree for nodes of type *REROUTE* and then check their input and output socket paths and reconnect them while deleting the reroute node, since there is no direct way to dissolve the node. In this example I traverse check the shader node tree of the material named "Material":

```
import bpy

node_tree = bpy.data.materials['Material'].node_tree

for node in node_tree.nodes[:]:

    if node.type != 'REROUTE':
        continue

    input_socket = node.inputs[0]
    output_socket = node.outputs[0]

    for link in output_socket.links:
        node_tree.links.new(input_socket.links[0].from_socket, link.to_socket)

    node_tree.nodes.remove(node)
```

Comment: As core Python dev, [Raymond Hettinger says](https://youtu.be/OSGv2VnC0go?t=1200): *"if you mutate something you're iterating over, you're living in a state of sin and deserve whatever happens to you"*. Iterate over a copy of nodes like so: `for node in node_tree.nodes[:]:`. BTW, no need for the check if there are any outward links, because you can iterate over an empty iterable (will do nothing). Also no need to use `len(...) > 0`, as for non-bool values Python will apply `bool()` which returns `False` for an empty collection and `True` for a non-empty collection.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady oops oh yeah correct, i didnt realize i was modifying that im iterating over lol thanks for pointing that out XD

Comment: thanks markus. yes no need the > 0 check, i was testing stuff and forgot to remove that check. i made the change thank you hehe